# The TA-Lib and IQoptionapi is Not Working

Tags: python, bots, ta-lib

i am making a bot using TA-Lib and iqoptionapi by following [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7Y9gw3jw1g) Tutorial.

I follow everything he did but when i run the python code it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\for Test Python\Test Python Bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    data_rsi = RSI(close, timeperiod=14)[-1]
  File "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\talib\__init__.py", line 64, in wrapper
    result = func(*_args, **_kwds)
TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got list)
```

i don't know what am i doing wrong, Please tell me how can i get rid of this problem i am not a good developer Please Help me.

Thanks For Your Time.

TA-Lib version: `0.4.24`

iqoptionapi version: `6.8.9.1`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

> Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got list)

Wrap your arguments with `numpy.array` as in this example:

```
import numpy as np
import talib as tb

close = np.array([100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0])

tb.RSI(close, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, But what are these numbers in the array and that is "TSV"

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted from another code sample. It's fixed now. It supposed to be RSI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but... what are these values in the np.array ??

Comment: Just a random float numbers.

Comment: is it necessary to add these numbers?

Comment: no its not necessary

Comment: So if i just add ```close = np.array([100.0])``` will it work?

Comment: yes. do you realise what these numbers are stands for?

Comment: Nope. I did not :P

Comment: Can you Please Tell Me What these numbers Stands For ??